# Today 2018-08-02, upgrading to 18.04.1 crashes gnome

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 18.04, crash

Today my system was asking me to upgrade to 18.04.1 (from a recent upgrade to 18.04). After finishing the upgrade and rebooting, now the computer boots to a TTY only. After loging in with my credentials, I can restart the desktop manager with the command:

`sudo service gdm restart`

but that doesn't bring back my old gnome desktop. All settings are gone too.
Can somebody help me to boot directly to the graphical interface?
Somebody with a similar experience?

Help is greatly appreciated 
P.S. (I am a normal user only and not familiar with the inner workings of Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trying I could solve the problem by performing the following steps (although I do not know what actually did the job, sorry)

1. install all recent updates
2. re-install gnome via

   `apt-get install gnome`
3. set defaults via

   `update-rc.d -f gdm3 defaults`

(a window pops up asking for your password)

after reboot, now I end up directly in the GUI again.
The login-screen uses the US-English keyboard layout and ignores my settings but once inside the GUI the preset default is automatically active again).